# Two Consecutive for loop in C++, Second loop is not working

Tags: c++, for-loop, dev-c++

Objective: I have two arrays. 1st Array is: evenList and the 2nd is: oddList. I want to print the even and odd numbers between the given ranges in this format.

[image: Screenshot; Print Even and Odd Numbers]

This is my code,

```
cout << "\nEven numbers between " << lowerLimit << " to " << upperLimit << ": ";

for(int i; i < evenList.size(); i++){
    cout << evenList[i] << "  ";
}

cout << "\n\nOdd numbers between " << lowerLimit << " to " << upperLimit << ": ";

for(int j; j < oddList.size(); j++){
    cout << oddList[j] << "  ";
}
```

the first for loop prints the desired output but the second loop don't show the odd numbers. Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot; Undesired Output]

I've read some of contents about for loops already but I just can't get the answer. If someone facing the same question or problem and got the answer, please share. I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Please initialise your iterators  to 0 in the loop.  Something like this,
for(int i = 0; i < evenList.size(); i++)

Comment: Don't show images of text, copy-paste the text *as text* into the question. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And always try to create a proper [mcve] to show us.

Comment: Note: For portability (and in my personal opinion, nicer code), use `std::endl` instead of `\n` for new lines.

Comment: Please turn on compiler warnings and then *fix them*. Try `-Wall -Wextra` options for *gcc* (which I belileve Dev-C++ uses), search where you can set compiler options in your IDE. In this case the compiler would have directly told you what the problem is, for example.

Comment: @fredrik While I agree overall, `\n` on a text stream should always do the right thing. Or at least I don't know of a platform where it does not.

Comment: @fredrik Using `std::endl` is the same as using `"\n" << std::flush`. Using plain `'\n'` for a newline is almost always enough.

Comment: @hyde What about Windows?

Comment: @fredrik That's why you have *binary mode* and *text mode* files and streams. A text mode stream will automatically translate plain `'\n'` into the correct end-of-line sequence for the platform. And do the opposite translation when reading (e.g. `\r\n` into `\n`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not initializing your iterators. `int i;` should be `int i = 0;`, and likewise for `int j`. As it is now, this is undefined behavior. It's just chance that it worked the first time and not the second time, it might as well work both times, not work at all, crash right off the bat or do something entirely different.

---

Does your compiler emit a warning for this code? Ideally, it should say something like "uninitialized local variable 'i' used". Always listen to compiler warnings, they can help point out some common mistakes. If your compiler issues no warning here, try to see if you can configure it to be more strict with warnings.

Comment: When I initialize my i and j, I got my desired output. Thanks @Blaze . I have two questions, first: Should I initialize all *int*s to 0? Second: Compiler dont show any errors like "uninitialized local variable". Is there a settings for that?

Comment: You don't have to initialize them to `0` specifically, but generally you should initialize or set the variables to a value before reading them (this includes `++` which has to read the value in order to increase it afterwards). As for the compiler warning it depends on what compiler you use - for GCC it's `-Wuninitialized` (but best just set the `-Wall` instead to enable warnings for much other issues, too).

Answer (score 0):

I have two point that is leading you to your undesired output.

1. It is always good to initialize a variable. In most cases, it might lead you to segmentation fault. In the above code, you've not initialized the variables in the for loop.
2. I have not used C++ but I suppose that you're using array, **evenList** and **oddList**.  And you're using a condition `j<oddList.size()`.  The only way this condition can go wrong is if doesn't have any element in **oddList** array. Check whether you have any elements in those array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ***FOR EACH LOOP*** to prevent the variable initialization confusion.

```
for(string s : eventList){ cout << s << endl; }
```

and same for the second loop. Hope this time it works

Answer (score 0):

You can also use а Range-based for loop

```
cout<<"\nEven numbers between " << lowerLimit << " to " << upperLimit << ": ";
for (const auto &e: evenList)
{
    cout << e << "  ";
}

cout << "\n\nOdd numbers between " << lowerLimit << " to " << upperLimit << ": ";

for (const auto &o: oddList)
{
    cout << o << "  ";
}
```